# can't check the type of the file being uploaded

Tags: php, file-upload, file-extension

I have this function to check if the file is an image or not, but it always returning false

```
function upload_file($file) {
    if($file['type'] != "image/jpeg" || $file['type'] != "image/gif") {
                        $errors[] = "Please upload a photograph with extenstion of JPEG, JPG, GIF or BMP.";
                        return false;
    }
}
```

so can anyone tell me where i gone wrong here!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needs to use `&&`:

```
if($file['type'] != "image/jpeg" && $file['type'] != "image/gif") {
```

By using `||` you're causing it to always be false since no image can be both a jpeg and a gif

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($file['type'] != "image/jpeg" || $file['type'] != "image/gif") {
```

should be

```
 if($file['type'] !== "image/jpeg" || $file['type'] !== "image/gif") {
```

**edit: nevermind, this doesnt matter**

Comment: Actually that just ads a type comparison to the check which isn't an issue here